# How do I make a composite key with SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, key

How do I make a composite key with SQL Server Management Studio?

I want two *INT* columns to form the identity (unique) for a table

Answer (score 374):

[image]

1. Open the design table tab
2. Highlight your two INT fields (Ctrl/Shift+click on the grey blocks in the very first column)
3. Right click -> Set primary key

Comment: To highlight multiple fields, click the blocks in front of the columns "column name" and "data type" and such. Ctrl/Shift+Clicking on the column name fields won't actually do anything.

Comment: So if one is a string and the other is an int, it's not possible? Doesn't seem to be...

Comment: I would downvote this but then I realised the OP specifically asked for how to do it in SSMS.  You should always script database changes + if you use tools like this, you'll never learn how to do the changes for yourself

Comment: @JonnyLeeds thats a very high horse your on there. Whats wrong with GUI if that's what people prefer?

Comment: @leinad13 I must have been having a bad day!  But the major problem is that they aren't repeatable and it generally means that people are making uncontrolled ad hoc changes and tweaks to fix database/schema problems.  That's a very bad sign - they are undocumented (eg by having the code to fix written down and checked into version control and/or having a tool that automatically applies the right changes to whatever the database version is) and if you have more than one installation then you're in serious trouble as soon the databases won't have the same schema

Comment: @JonnyRaa Indeed, it is good to script database changes. In SQL Server Management Studio, one can script out databases, database tables, indexes, etc. For example, one can create a table and set up a primary key and an index using the GUI, and then script out the results by right-clicking the table and choosing Script Table as... This tool has helped me learn how to do things in T-SQL that I could previously only do through the SSMS GUI.

Answer (score 70):

here is some code to do it:

```
-- Sample Table
create table myTable 
(
    Column1 int not null,
    Column2 int not null
)
GO

-- Add Constraint
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_myConstraint PRIMARY KEY (Column1,Column2)
GO
```

I added the constraint as a separate statement because I presume your table has already been created.

Comment: I guess this answer fits since you can run this within Query window of SSMS... ;)

Comment: Scripting FTW, and for explicit naming! The external `ADD PRIMARY KEY` and internal `PRIMARY KEY` definitions will give random names to the keys, which can make it a pain the bajingo to figure which belongs where if you don't have the db diagram + tables.

Comment: This creates a non-clustered constraint. Are you sure you want that, given that you also want a composite key?

Answer (score 45):

```
create table my_table (
    id_part1 int not null,
    id_part2 int not null,
    primary key (id_part1, id_part2)
)
```

Answer (score 18):

In design mode (right click table select modify) highlight both columns right click and choose set primary key

Answer (score 8):

Open up the table designer in SQL Server Management Studio (right-click table and select 'Design')

Holding down the Ctrl key highlight two or more columns in the left hand table margin

Hit the little 'Key' on the standard menu bar at the top

You're done..

:-)

Answer (score 6):

```
create table myTable 
(
    Column1 int not null,
    Column2 int not null
)
GO


ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD  PRIMARY KEY (Column1,Column2)
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

Highlight both rows in the table design view and click on the key icon, they will now be a composite primary key.

I'm not sure of your question, but only one column per table may be an IDENTITY column, not both.