# Creating composite primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

How to add composite primary keys in SQL Server 2008?

I have a table as follows.

```
testRequest (wardNo nchar(5)
            , BHTNo nchar(5)
            , testID nchar(5)
            , reqDateTime datetime);
```

I need `wardNo, BHTNo` and `testID` to be a composite primary key.

How can I do this in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I make a composite key with SQL Server Management Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545571/how-do-i-make-a-composite-key-with-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you use management studio, simply select the wardNo, BHTNo, testID columns and click on the key mark in the toolbar.

[image]

Command for this is,

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.testRequest
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TestRequest 
PRIMARY KEY (wardNo, BHTNo, TestID)
```

Comment: What is the name of the toolbar?

Comment: @usefulBee Table Designer

Comment: Works perfectly. Also a point to note the fields must not be nullable

Answer (score 40):

How about this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.testRequest
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TestRequest 
PRIMARY KEY (wardNo, BHTNo, TestID)
```

Comment: This is good. Practicing query in sql is always challenging !

Answer (score 30):

How about something like

```
CREATE TABLE testRequest (
        wardNo nchar(5),
        BHTNo nchar(5),
        testID nchar(5),
        reqDateTime datetime,
        PRIMARY KEY (wardNo, BHTNo, testID)
);
```

Have a look at this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e8c0/3/0)

Answer (score 5):

it simple, select columns want to insert primary key and click on Key icon on header and save table[image: sql composite key]

happy coding..,