# Can you have a Primary Key references another Primary Key from a different table? If so, in what case or situation would this be used?

Tags: sql, primary-key

Creating a table with Primary Key (customer_id) which matches another PK from another table, and trying to reference that.

```
    CREATE TABLE customer_leads(
        customer_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
        first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        signup_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        duration TIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
        )
```

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS A PK is unique not null & a FK references a unique. When either happens declare it, if it isn't already implied by another declaration. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406731/3404097

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this makes sense.  It *would* make sense like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_leads(
    customer_lead_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    . . . 
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
    . . . 
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer_leads(customer_lead_id)
);
```

This formulation says that every customer starts out as a customer lead.  The "customer_id" is assigned at the lead level, and some of these are eventually turned into customers.

This makes sense.  The foreign key reference is from the `customers` table.  All customers have valid leads, but not all leads are (necessarily) valid customers.

Your structure is troublesome.  Basically, the `customer_id` is assigned in customer leads -- by the serial column.  Then, this is supposed to be a reference to the primary key of another table.  But how is that value calculated?  The structure doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I see. I don't think I have a clear understanding of what REFERENCES is actually doing or its purpose. In order to have your PK reference another PK, you set that as a Foreign Key as you did with 'customers' table? Also, why did you not have customer_id in SERIAL? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mir . . . Normally, these would be different keys.  But the question is specifically about having a primary key also be a foreign key.