# Composite key in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create composite key in sql server.
What is the maximum limit of columns, which i can combine to create composite key in sql server 2008 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545571/how-do-i-make-a-composite-key-with-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
But, i want to know the max. limit of column , which i can use to create composite key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server Maximum Capacity Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> Columns per primary key  16

(And similarly for indexes, foreign keys, etc). So, 16.

But, as with so many questions, if you have to *ask* about the limit, you're probably doing something wrong.

Can you identify anything in everyday life that requires 16 distinct pieces of data to uniquely identify it?

---

Alternatively, your question might be construed to be about the *width* of the columns that can go into the key. That's also answered on the same page:

> Bytes per primary key 900

Comment: Thanks, Damien. Nice link. I bookmark it. :). And again thanks a lot for quick and genuine reply.