# SQL Server - Composite key creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a composite primary key like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (Column1 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, Column2 nvarchar(3) NOT NULL, Column3 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL)

ALTER TABLE TableA ADD CONSTRAINT PK_AuxGroupData PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Column1 , Column2)
```

By some reason, the second query is generating the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException occurred   Message=**The
>   constraint specified is not valid**.   Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET
>   Data Provider   HResult=-2147217900   NativeError=25505

This happens when I run my project from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in Debug Mode.

My development machine has:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
- Microsoft SQL Server
  2008 Compact 3.5 SP2 x64 ENU

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server Compact Edition does not support clustered indexes.  This goes for the Primary Key as well.

Link showing that it does not support clustered indexes:
  - [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345331(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345331%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Link showing that PRIMARY KEYs are maintained by unique indexes:
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173393.aspx

Comment: Thats a shame... Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545571/how-do-i-make-a-composite-key-with-sql-server-management-studio indicates that it *is* possible.

Comment: @ClayShannon - That question is about SQL-Server, not SQL-Server-CE specifically.  This question is specifically about SQL-Serve-CE, which has much more limited functionality.

Comment: Ah, yes; I was focused on my issue, and failed to notice that.