# add a constraint on a datetime column

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

i want to to add a constraint onto a ID column and a date time column, so that an id can only be entered once in a day

```
alter table Table1  
...
add constraint pk_id Primary Key (datetime,ID)
```

If an `id` has been inserted for the following `datetime 2015-03-17 12:48:00`, it would not get inserted again on the same datetime, but if the time changes to `2015-03-17 12:45:00` the `id` gets entered again.

Is there a way to add the constraint to just the date part of the datetime column?

Comment: if you're not concerned with the time portion can you not just change it to a date instead of a datetime?

Comment: no i need the datetime for other needs.its just in this instance

Comment: ideal scenario for creating instead of trigger .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can but you have different alternatives:

- Change your column to just have the date part populated
- Create a computed column where you remove the time part and create the unique index used this column instead.

EDIT: as per @a-ツ comment there are other options:

- Split the column in two, one to store the date and other to store the time part, so you can create de index over the date one

Comment: 3rd: he/she could split the column in a date and a time column

Comment: Thanks. i thought they would be a way to do it with the datetime value, but i will split the columns up

Answer (score -1):

You have to give composite primary key or check constraint..

Check this example. For composite key, on design mode, just select both column and right click and select "primary-key".

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [datecolumn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC,
    [datecolumn] ASC
)

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into Table_1 values (1, '2014-03-17 00:00:00.000', 'othercolumnvalue')

insert into Table_1 values  (1, '2014-03-17 12:00:00.000', 'othercolumnvalue')
insert into Table_1 values  (1, '2014-03-17 02:10:59.000', 'othercolumnvalue')

--this will give error as you already entered the same value.
insert into Table_1 values (1, '2014-03-17 00:00:00.000', 'othercolumnvalue')
```

[how do I make a composite key with SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545571/how-do-i-make-a-composite-key-with-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: He wants to ingore the date time part: "Is there a way to add the constraint to just the date part of the datetime column?"

Comment: thanks dear. I give the answer as he need. means if time part is differ, insert it.